# Aliens want to do science experiments on humans

Tags: humans, aliens, interspecies-relations

If humans encountered an alien species, what would we do?  Probably kill some and put them in plastic bags to take back to earth.  We would probably capture some and put them in cages and do all sorts of horrible experiments on them such as dissection and stuff.

This is all fine and nice, but what if intelligent aliens came to earth and wanted to do this to humans to figure out what we are?  How would we (non-violently) stop them from abducting people and doing nasty science experiments on us?

Comment: You said "non-violently", right?

Comment: How advanced are the aliens compared to us? how much danger do they pose? can they understand human speech (translator etc.)

Comment: If they can come to Earth, their technology is so far above us, we would be helpless. Especially non-violently. Otherwise, play the XCOM series.

Comment: When you say they don't understand speech, do you mean just audible sounds or any kind of communication? If it's the former, we have plenty of other means to communicate (like writing, or digital radio transmissions). If it's the latter... how intelligent can they really be, and how did they get here?

Comment: I will edit the post to try to clear things up.

Comment: According to the help center: *If a system, event or element... we are here to help.* The help center also states: *If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site...* The principle question here, therefore, is one of whether or not we are asking about humanity as an in-universe actor, or we are asking about the human reaction (as a non-actor) in context to the invasion as an event. I think, contextually speaking, this is asking on the basis of the former rather than the latter, and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: This is in the VTR queue, but I need to vote to keep it closed.  (a) Aliens that have the tech to get to our planet, probe our people, and steal cow lips are somewhat by definition *unstoppable* by the tech standards we have today.  (b) Abduction (and subsequent probing/lip-removal) is inherently violent and without ethics or morals on behalf of the abductees/lipless.  I'm having trouble seeing how a Ghandi-esque starvation protest would do anything other than help the process along.  This Q feels like it's missing serious details about the aliens (tech, psychology, justification, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Communication is a key aspect of any advance Race. It doesn't matter how they communicate, because there will always be a transmission of some form of wave, action or imagery that we will be able to detect and decode. Its just a matter of time until a translation is created between the two, given they are not immediately hostile.

The issue is how an Alien species decides to make contact with us. If they are simply kidnapping people to perform experiments on, and refuse to communicate, then there is no real non-violent way for humanity to prevent this. No one is going to sit outside an alien space ship in silent protest and let them take you in to be tortured.

What your Aliens should realize is that humans can communicate and are intelligent creatures. From that assumption, they should try and open communication channels peacefully. After all, having an entire planet hostile to your single ship isn't exactly the ideal situation, and a humans knowledge of that planet will be far more advance that your aliens.

So your aliens arrive, they detect all sorts of waves flying through the sky. They see mouths moving, hand motions, written text, digital binary. They detect vibrations in the air then a human mouth moves. They notice that this thing called a TV is sending out some for of message that all the other humans seem to understand. They establish communication channels with the humans to form a translation between the two languages and simply negotiate for details about the biology of the humans or for human samples.

Answer (score 0):

1) You physically prevent them from doing so. Any action they want to take against to populace, you create a shield wall, and deny them further access. If they use force, you either use bigger, stronger shields or escalate in accordance.

2) You repeat every action they take against you, against them. That may stop them.

3) Gently bound and imprison them, every time they try something funny. If the humans are stronger than the aliens, it can be done pretty much non-violently.

Otherwise, the same goes when humans are in conflict, and one want to be left alone, while the other doesn't understand it.

**So much depends on the circumstances and capabilities of the involved parties.**

Comment: That is a personal approach that does not account for technology (basicly "what if one alien randomly spawned on earth) But here is the problem: "Hello, my new earth friend. Let me greet you in my species' common way: by pressuring your VARUY until you speak in reliefe. I don't yet know where your VARUY is so I test different spots until I hear the wanted reaction. Ahh, there it is, just like us, it's the center of the body. ... Ahh, you are learning quickly, thank you for sharing my customs. Ah, there are more of you kind and they approach swiftly, I shall give them a quick greeting too."

Answer (score 0):

In short: If they find us first, we can't **make** them do anything. Our ways of communication *might* be different, our mindsets ***will*** be different and our best chance of survival is to engage communication. If they don't react to it, non-violent approaches are doomed anyway and if they do, they are somewhat curious and if we share that, we might get on common ground.

---

There are far to many unknowns about that other species and the encounter to give a real answer but here are my thought on it:

I don't think we would kill aliens for samples in that first scenario and I don't think that there could be a space traveling species that does not know any concept of complex communication. Speech is just one way to communicate and communication is just one way to learn something about a species.

Given a tech boost that enables interstellar travel, we would most likely (we actually do) look out for two types of planets: inhabitable ones and inhabited ones (they won't be the same since different kinds of environments may support life and the probability of independently evolving systems of life being all similar or even partly interchangeable, is close to zero even given that there are multiple systems of life. When we look out for aliens, the first contact will be visual (if you want to call radiotelescopes "visual") and we can see and assess them years if not ages before our first probe reaches their orbit, which in turn will be years if not ages before the first manned mission reaches them. We can easily detect nuclear events, space tarvel and other signs of technology from lightyears away and as we come closer, we can study their population, macro movements, etc. and later we can zoom in and get firt impressions of their "personal" behavior,

At that point, the authorities ore some rich tech company will decide how to approach them. Given pre-1960 technologies, we could send orbiters that investigate closer, if they have a space program, we should just send them some data [like we did as a PR-gag before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_Golden_Record) (and monitor their reaction closely).

Alien species for sure do not think like us (not even earth animals do - hell, not even speakers of fundamentally different languages think alike). They will, however, have a similar time schedule for meeting us (assuming they aren't just a crew of random idiots that have been abandoned by there people - in that case, I expect the [dolphins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#So_Long,_and_Thanks_for_All_the_Fish) to handle it - or just accidentally drop out of warp - lrt's hope that old stargate is still liing around somewhere and they need our help to find it). They will most likely have some sort of telemetry and increasingly accurate readings long before they reach us so they would already know quite a lot about us and would weight if and how to approach us.

Given the fact that we monitor space with a variety of means, it is unlikely that they could study us closely without us noticing but they could decide that a meeting with a somewhat intelligent species that dominates its planet through aggression and dominance and is able to fire nukes into space is not worth the risk, or that they want to eliminate us for whatever reason or that they come to learn about us. Only the latter case is interesting here since they can reach us and we can't reach them so there's nothing we can do about the other cases. If they decide to study us, they would most likely be very careful (I assume they didn't come straight form heaven but had to evolve at their own planet so they know how to study things, how to make assumptions and how to survive when facing unfamiliar consciousnesses).

For a space traveling species to develop, it is *stellarly* unlikely that they don't share some of our characteristics. They would need efficient ways to:

- Gather and distribute resources
- Ensure the survival of their species at least to the point where they become immortal or can reproduce with help of their technology alone
- gather, preserve, utilize and revise knowledge and skills

So it is relatively safe to say that they developed some equivalent of moral (to distribute resources and keep the gang together) at some point in their history. Let's hope they are a social species and have not yet abandoned that trait in the infinite void of space, alone with their computers.

Again, to prevent them from harming us, we don't need to talk, we just need to make them understand us and hope that they don't harm sentient/self-aware beings. They will know that there is intelligent life on this planet long before they reach earth so they had time to think about what they want with us. If they want to learn, they show curiosity and since they did not destroy their home planet before they could leave for space, they don't act violently as a rule.

Only in a case like this can we hope to non-violently protect us from being harmed but if these conditions line up, it should be fairly easy. It might cause some casualties but if they want to learn, they will most likely send messages and see if/how we react to their form of communication, they might take some samples and figure out what kind of things kill us and that they should not do them if they want to learn. And we, on the other hand, would do our best to mimic their way of communication (just try any method of communication we are capable of, really) and establish some mutual understanding. As soon as one side figures out how to communicate, curiosity will take the better of us and probably most species that left their planet (imminent threads make poor motivators for space programs since the right threads don't normally align themselves to be just solvable in time with the given level of technology). If the voice line is established, we can try to share concepts. It is unlikely that any side will fully understand even a single concept of the other one's mindset but observe and mimic is quite powerful and hopefully, some principals truly are universal (like reciprocity and it's increment: our basic moral).